# CAF receiver: VMAP Ads and Subtitles

Tags: android, ads, chromecast, google-cast, vast

Android app creates MediaLoadRequestData with MediaInfo object and loads it to RemoteMediaClient. CAF receiver plays the video properly and shows the ads when needed.
Issue occurs when I try changing the subtitles using Expanded Controls on my Android app. Clicking on another text track doesn't do anything. It closes the caption selector dialog, but the subtitles are not shown.

This only happens when I include VMAP ads with my MediaInfo object. Subtitles are normally shown, when there are no ads.

VastAdsRequest object is created and set to MediaInfo object as follows:

```
val vmapRequest: VastAdsRequest.Builder = VastAdsRequest.Builder()
vmapRequest.setAdTagUrl(vastUrl)
mediaInfo.setVmapAdsRequest(vmapRequest.build())
```

It doesn't matter whether I use default CAF receiver app ID, or my custom implementation of CAF receiver.

Is there something I am missing, and how should I approach this problem?